# what is the difference between event binding and property binding?

Tags: angular, typescript, model-view-controller

In the architecture of angular 2 there are two terms Event binding and Property binding. What is the difference between them?[image: Architecture of Angular2]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#Property binding -

In case you have to pass the value from parent component to child component (whether the value is static or dynamic) we have to use the `property binding` that mean by doing so we send the value using attribute on component and receive it in the child component by using `@Input` decorator for example of property binding see here -

```
<my-child [myProp]="myProp" />
```

#Event Binding -

Catching the Child's Event/method from the parent component

whenever we have to fire some event on click or something else from child component and pass to the parent component, we have to use `Event Binding` see here in the example below -

```
<my-child [myProp]="myProp" (onPropChange)="onPropChange($event)" />
```

here we have `onPropChange` as output event binding, we can fire that event using EventEmitter.

for more detail see here

- https://www.patrickschadler.com/property-event-binding-angular-2/

Comment: Is the both are used for one-way binding or two-way binding?

Comment: Property binding for sure for one way binding, but event binding callback function into parent component

Comment: Now i am cleared about data binding in angular 2.Thank you:)

Comment: The first link is broken :(

Answer (score 3):

**Line 1:**

```
input [value]="username" (input)="username = $event.target.value"
```

**Line 2:**

```
Hello {{username}}!
```

Let’s take a closer look at what’s going on here:

- `[value]=”username”` - Binds the expression username to the input element’s value property.
- `(input)=”expression”` - Is a declarative way of binding an expression to the input element’s input event (yes there’s such event).
- `username = $event.target.value` - The expression that gets executed when the input event is fired.
- `$event` - Is an expression exposed in event bindings by Angular, which has the value of the event’s payload.

Considering these observations, it becomes very clear what’s happening. We’re binding the value of the username expression to the input’s value property (data goes into the component).