# Better to read $event object or component field in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, event-binding

Let's say we have a component whose template has a simple dropdown. Whenever the user makes a selection in the dropdown, the event-handler is fired `onSelect()`

```
<select [value]="this.selectedCountryName" 
  (change)="onSelect()">
  <option *ngFor="let country of this.countries"> 
 {{country.name}}</option>
</select>
```

and the corresponding event-handler might do something like this

```
public onSelect(): void {
  console.log('User selected ' + this.selectedCountryName)
}
```

But I've also seen implementations where you pass the $event object through to the event-handler, like so:

```
<select [value]="this.selectedCountryName"
  (change)="onSelect($event)">
  <option *ngFor="let country of this.countries">
  {{country.name}}</option>
</select>
```

And perhaps you would just reference the selected value from $event object, as opposed to trying to read it from the component fields.

Somewhat similar to the Angular documentation: https://angular.io/guide/user-input

**Is one approach preferred over the other?**

Comment: take a look to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40188550/what-is-the-difference-between-event-binding-and-property-binding

Comment: I understand what Property Bindings and Event Bindings are... it’s the best practice I’m curious about.

Answer (score 0):

The second aproach is better when you have to calculate something before to asign the value. But if you just want to use the value your are free to use anyone you want